# In excel sheet how to filter specific rows which have specific values

Tags: excel, filter

In this table, I want to filter the rows which have at least one zero but not the rows which have all zero values.

This means the resulting table should remove  R3, R4 and R6 rows and the rest should be in the resulting table

[image]

Comment: you can create a helper column that sums these values, and filter values = 0 (this means all columns = 0 )

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have updated the question again. I have misunderstood the problem earlier. Please if you can give me an answer to the updated question. Thanks again

Comment: R3 should not be removed . It does not have 0 in all columns

Comment: The requirement is, remove rows which have all zero values and the rows which do not have any zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a helper column with the formula, at `Cell H2`, paste the following formula and drag it down.

```
=AND(SUM(B2:G2)>0;COUNTIF(B2:G2;0)>0)
```

This will produce `True` only if both conditions are satisfied:

- **Cond1** : at least one number bigger than 0 : `SUM(B2:G2)>0`
- **Cond2** : at least one 0 occurrence : `COUNTIF(B2:G2;0)>0`

I'm using pt_BR, so note that:

- `Verdadeiro = True`
- `Falso = False`

[image]

Then after that you can add a filter and clean your data using the helper column located at column H.

[image]

Displaying only rows where the helper column is equal to `True`

[image]